# PayPal REST API - how to obtain API credentials?

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm currently trying to get access to the PayPal REST API with my company's Business Account, but I don't seem to be able to choose an account from the dropdown menu (I've created several different Sandbox accounts already).

[image: REST App Screen]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you created the test account as per the message?

Comment: @ChrisBint as I said, I created multiple sandbox accounts. Where/how would I create a Test account?

Comment: Are the accounts business accounts? When you create the sandbox account, you have choice to business or personal.

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Robert I have both, two BUSINESS accounts (one US, one DE) and one PREMIER account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this screen, on the left side, under "Sandbox", choose Accounts. Create a new Business account and then try again.

If this does not work, I would suggest the following:

1) Try in a different browser
2) Clear cache & cookies
3) Delete existing sandbox accounts and then create a new one.
4) Nuclear option: Open a brand new PayPal account for use in the sandbox and create a new sandbox account there.

Comment: I am surprised. Creating another, fourth BUSINESS account actually worked. I have no idea why, but it works - thanks for your support!

Comment: It can also take some time, till the new accounts show up. It did not work for me first but after I logged in to the newly created account, it showed up.